# Manually merge two Linux kernel configs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration

I'm working on configuring a Linux kernel for my laptop (Apple M1), and I have two different configs: one is a minimal config I made myself for an arm64 vm image, and one is the default config used by the distro, which includes many unnecessary options for myself (Asahi Linux in this case).

I'm aware of the `diffconfig` script in the tree to examine which config values differ, as well as the `merge_config` script to apply options from one config over top of another, but what I would like is a script acting similar to `make oldconfig` for updating kernel configs, taking the two reference configs as input and prompting for a choice whenever the two disagree (that is, don't take either config as "correct", allow me to choose manually where they differ). Is there any tool available to achieve this goal? I tried searching for something, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I mean, you already write the answer: `merge_config`.

Comment: Does `merge_config` not simply overwrite one config file with the other?

Comment: `comm -3 <(sort config1) <(sort config2)` See `man comm` or the [tag:comm] tag

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the challenge you describe and found a tool called [`meld`](http://meldmerge.org) which worked really well with a cool interface. It's available prepackaged for many Linux distributions, and also on [Flathub](https://flathub.org/en-GB/apps/search?q=meld).

It compares two files (say `a` and `b`) and allows you to select whether to merge differences from `a` to `b` or `b` to `a`.